# Fetching app details, app icons, app screenshots from Google play store

Tags: android

Does anybody has any idea how AppBrain like applications work? I want to make an application which can list only selected publisher's apps, I referred previously asked question "Fetch details of application from Google play using package name?", but did not get any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [unofficial API available](https://github.com/thetutlage/Google-Play-Store-API)

> Play Store API is an unofficial version of Google Play Store which
>   will let you pullup applications from google play store using18
>   different functions covering almost everything from google store